# String search in DTS

Tags: dts

Does anyone know of a way to search DTS packages for specific strings?. I saw this http://www.dtspowersearch.com in google search. Any feed back on this tool or anyother tool or pointers on how to accompolish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use the object model to enumerate the properties of a DTS package.

See [here](http://www.nigelrivett.net/ScriptDTSProperties.html) for an example, which gives instructions for creating a DTS package with a script task which will output DTS packages properties to a file.